# How can I copy pages successfully from existing wordpress website to new replacement website

Tags: wordpress

I am building a new replacement wordpress website. I will be using same home page and some of the same pages and posts on my new website.

I have tried to export some pages via the current live website from the dashboard menu / tools / export. But there seems to be an error where file cannot be retrieved properly. I receive a message: `XML cannot be opened because there is no available data view (XSLT).`

Is there any other simple way I can successfully copy home page, some other pages and posts from my existing to new wordpress website.

Any help given will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Export/import should work. Your problem may depend on the xml file size. I have found that if the file is > .3 meg, the import will time out. I solved it in my case by using a utility called wxr file splitter. Then, import each split file separately. I have used it on a file that was so large I had to split it into 14 pieces. But it worked.